# How can I authorize a user without using the browser?

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

My app is Windows based, and there is IE installed.  But my app will run in a process which does not like externally-launched applications (like a web browser, when authorizing).  Instead, my app will use the host application's web features to display a browser.

The host app takes over the front-end and is a public kiosk-type application, so I have no control over how browsing gets launched.  The google drive api automatically launches the default browser (with an affinity toward Chrome, even if not the default...  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant give code examples, but you need to look into non browser based auth - i.e. server side authentication https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server?hl=en